# Typeorm find with and & or where block

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to build below query in typeorm.

```
SELECT * from Department where
type = 'Employee' and
((from_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03'AND '2013-01-09') OR 
(to_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2013-01-09') OR 
(from_date <= '2013-01-03' AND to_date >= '2013-01-09'))
```

Below is my typeorm equivalent.

```
connection.find(Department, {
      where: [
        { fromDate: Between(filter.fromDate, filter.toDate) },
        { toDate: Between(filter.fromDate, filter.toDate) },
        {
          fromDate: LessThanOrEqual(filter.fromDate),
          toDate: MoreThanOrEqual(filter.toDate),
        },
      ],
      andWhere: { type: 'Employee' },
    });
```

But somehow I am getting wrong number of output. It is as if andWhere is not working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure it's a valid option. I think you have either 2 choices: add "type" to every "or" clause, or use the queryBuilder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let qb = this.repository.createQueryBuilder("department");

qb.where("department.type= :type", {type: "Employee"});
qb.andWhere("((department.from_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03'AND '2013-01-09') OR 
(department.to_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2013-01-09') OR 
(department.from_date <= '2013-01-03' AND department.to_date >= '2013-01-09'))");
```